# Host Images from Link

Tags: uploads, media-library, import, migration

Recently, I imported all my post from Blogger, so all the images showing in the post currently reside on Blogger's server. I want to import/put all those images to my server and automatically change each link for each image.

Since there are so many images and so many post I can not go one by one individually.

Please guide me on how to do that or redirect me to a plugin that does this job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Chip said; the native importer tool (look in Tools > Import) should have imported everything. But if it didn't, and you already have the rest of the content, you can run this plugin to bring over all your images:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cache-images/

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

wordPress has [a native Blogger importer](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#Blogger). Did you check the "Download attachments" checkbox during the import process?

Comment: there is no checkbox for "Download Attachments" . I used this one tho: (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/blogger-importer/)